# How to print uint8_t bytes array?

Tags: c, arrays, printf, uint8t

I have the following code:

```
uint16_t BufferSize = BUFFER_SIZE;
uint8_t Buffer[BUFFER_SIZE];
```

Buffer size is 64 bytes and is filled as:

```
Buffer[0] = 'P';
Buffer[1] = 'I';
Buffer[2] = 'N';
Buffer[3] = 'G';
Buffer[4] = 0;
Buffer[5] = 1;
Buffer[6] = 2;
Buffer[7] = 3;
Buffer[8] = 4;
.
.
.
Buffer[63] = 59;
```

I am trying to print the content of the Buffer using:

```
for( i = 0; i < BufferSize; i++ )
{

    PRINTF(Buffer[i]);

}
```

Also tried:

```
for( i = 0; i < BufferSize; i++ )
{
    PRINTF((const char*) Buffer[i]);
}
```

But it is not working.

Comment: *"But it is not working."* Please [edit] your question and explain what went wrong. Also, `PRINTF` is not standard C function, please show the definition of it.

Comment: How to print it depends on your usage of the array. If you store printable and non-printable characters you need to decide. Print a hexdump, or something else. For any help you need to show what your `PRINTF` macro is.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should refer to the syntax of `printf`. C treats small and capital letters differently so you should write something like this:

```
printf("%c", Buffer[i])
```

Answer (score 1):

1. `PRINTF` all caps is not a standard C function; C is case-sensitive, so you want `printf`.
2. Even so, when printing arbitrary strings you don't pass the string straight as the first argument to `printf`, as it may interpret some of its characters as placeholders for other arguments (say the string contains a `%`...). In general, pretty much any case when a `printf`-like function is invoked with anything but a string literal is suspect. So, you want `printf("%s", (const char *)Buffer)`, or `fputs((const char *)Buffer, stdout)` (generally slightly more efficient).
3. However, all these functions expect to work with NUL-terminated strings, not with counted buffers, so in your case they'll stop at the NUL just after `PING`. To actually output the whole buffer, you have to use an unformatted output function, such as `fwrite`: `fwrite(buffer, BufferSize, 1, stdout)`.

Answer (score 0):

Just `putchar` is better and faster.

```
int putchar(int character);
```

returns `EOF` on error, or `charater` itself otherwise.